# What's the format of my motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

I just found an old motherboard and i wonder what's the format, what's the powersupply and case i have to buy to make with this motherboard an new computer.
I know you have ATX or Baby ATX or MiniATX but i don't know what's the mine.

It's 20 centimeters large for 24,5 centimers long, it's not really big so i don't think it's a "classic" ATX motherboard. It's a Mercury motherboard and that's all i know. 
It's a radiator with fan on the CPU so i don't know the CPU type.

Thanks for trying to help me.

[Pic1](http://www.hiboox.fr/go/images/informatique/pic1,f90ef0cbf461a275f80f24d378e5fdc2.jpg.html)
[Pic2](http://www.hiboox.fr/go/images/informatique/pic2,078e5d7f0f6fde317d74555b6f37b2c7.jpg.html)

Comment: Can you post a photo?

Comment: Most motherboards also have a label that indicate the manufacture and model. knowing this information, you can (usually) find the manual online which will contain all the information you need.

Comment: if you remember what type of CPU was in it this would make things much easier

Comment: as a matter of fact judging by your pictures its still in there... remove the hs/fan and read the processor, the model should be engraved on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model is in the first pic, it's a Mercury KVM266PM-U version 3.0

http://www.mercury-pc.com/downloads_list.php?productid=510

Manual isn't available for download, but the drivers are there.  Based on the product specs, it's a micro-atx form factor.  The specs can be found here:

http://www.mercury-pc.com/product-spec.php?productid=510

Comment: Ok thanks, i just return to school to learn to read..

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Form Factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_form_factors) specifications for your MB dimensions.

As far as what CPU it supports, check the [CPU socket specs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_socket) and see which one matches yours. That will only tell you what type of processor it supports though, and not necessarily the max wattage.